# Compile Time vs Run Time (by looking at the code)

Tags: java, compilation

Most of the post does not answer this question very well, by giving some general definition and list some different types of errors compile time would throw vs run time.

But what exactly are the differences? Given a block of code how would you tell which part of the code would be in the compile time and what part would be in the run time?

for example the java code below:

```
void go(Bookmark[] items) {
  item[0] = new Movie();  // ArrayStoreException(Runtime) since Movie can not be casted to Book
}

go(new Book[1]); // Okay since Book is a subclass of BookMark
```

Would generate a RUNTIME error, but for instance how would you tell it is run time not compile time? Looks like everything could be inferred by just looking at the code i.e. we know that the parameter passed in go is of type Book[] and then in the go function we assign a Movie() to one of its element, so why can not we detect this at compile time? cant we see all this by just looking at the programme text by itself? So if compile time is not something that we could infer from reading the code text, then what exact is it, and how could we tell the difference from run time when looking at the code text?

Comment: What is the relationship between Bookmark and Book?

Comment: Book is a subclass of Bookmark

Comment: so then, your code won't compile you cant pass a `Book` array object into a method that takes `Bookmark` type array. That's a compile-time error